# What's a word for a person who feels they are an outsider to their own life?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

I'm writing an essay on somebody who is writing in their journal in third person and was looking for a word/character trait that will describe a person who feels that they are an outsider to their own life?

Comment: When this happens temporarily during a psychedelic experience, it's often called "ego death."  I don't think that's what you want, but just thought I'd mention it.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ego_death

Comment: They are ***detached***

Comment: Welcome to ELU.  It looks like you've already got a couple of answers there, although not formal ones.  With single word requests, ELU asks that you provide a sample sentence and show us the research you've done thus far to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A word to *describe* such a person is: self-alienated. The person writing this journal has become self-alienated.